# java swing aplication components out of place

Tags: java, swing

I have problem with `Java application`
Components seems to be out of place.
Problems apear only on one computer. Operating system is `Windows 10` with anniversary update. I am not sure if it is relevant but one of the other computers i tested application doesnt have anniversary update.
Other thing which makes this computer different is graphic card which is Intel `HD graphics 3000` (also not sure if it is relevant).

I am no expert and i feel like child in a fog when i try to solve this issue.

Application is written with java 7 sdk. But it doesnt look good on both jre 7 and 8 on this computer while it looks good with both jre's on every other computer i tested. I am not sure if i am going right direction but setting the environmental variable `J2D_D3D_NO_HWCHECK` to "true" only made things worse.

I am posting 2 screenshots. First one is from computer where it is misplaced and second one of how it is supposed to look like. It is only one difference of many i can see in application.

[image: problem]
[image: noproblem]

UPDATE:
I narrowed down this problem. Gap created in Windows and Windows Classic LookAndFeel is bigger.

```
try {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.getInstance().getPreferredGap(new javax.swing.JLabel(), new javax.swing.JLabel(), javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.SwingConstants.SOUTH, new javax.swing.JPanel()));
```

Code i provided is giving me 7 or 6 depending on machine. I tried running it on 2 machines with Windows 10 anniversary update both but still i got different results. Changeing LookAndFeel to CrossPlatform fixes problem in this situation. Although it might cause more problems in different panels in application.
I am unable to determine what might be the reason to getting different values from the same class on different computers with the same operating system version.

Comment: Check whether the frame has predefined or computed size (size of frame is set using the method `JFrame.setSize()` - predefined or `JFrame.pack()` - computed). If it's predefined your problem is that for some OS the frame can require more place. The best solution in this case is switch to computed size (if possible).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Problem was fixed size (280) made for Jpanel which was too small. Netbeans gui showed that Jpanel had prefered vertical size 274 while on other computers it is 258. So i checked some more. Vertical gap between most of components is set to "default small" which is actually 7. On every other computer in office it is also "default small" which is 6. Why is there different value on different computer?

Comment: *Why is there different value on different computer?*  All kinds of reasons.  Different size monitors with different resolutions, different graphics cards.  For anyone else reading this, this is why all Swing GUIs should be created without using any kind of window builder.  Swing GUIs should be built using the proper [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I don't know what is "default small". But in Swing it's very often, that the size of components is different for different settings. For example, if somebody sets the DPI to another value than standard (96)

Comment: method javax.swing.LayoutStyle.getInstance().getPreferredGap(.....) with same parameters on two computers returns different values. In my case it is 7 while on every other computers in office it is 6. LayoutStyle is never set so program should be using LayoutStyle provided by LookAndFeel which in all cases is the same it is "Windows" "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel". But for 2 different computers it gives different Layout Style. I tried reinstalling java. Different version of jre still return bigger gap then it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested i solved this issue

Changing Control Panel > Appearance and Personalisation > Display > Make text and other items larger or smaller

makes default button font size to get bigger. Default button font size is used by windows LookAndFeel to calculate gap size between components in LayoutStyle. LayoutStyle is used as default Layout on all components if one is not set.

Making text larger to 125% caused font size to increase by 2 points. After all math included in Windows LookAndFeel it made default small gap size increase from 6 points to 7.